# AD725 luma trap implementation

Tags: filter, simulation, video, analog-switch

*This question is related to my issues implementing luma trap on my bread board when it appeared that I get better results through composite output by disconnecting luma trap circuit at all. However using CXA1645 I really get positive effect of the luma trap circuitry, and I decided to revisit its implementation for AD725 in more detail.*

The luma trap / notch filter circuit itself comprising of the inductor and capacitor is extremely simple, and center frequency is calculated by the formulae

Fcenter=1/(2 * pi * sqrt(L*C))

for capacitor adjustment the formulae is

C=1/((Fc * 2 * pi)^2 * L)

My calculated ideal values for L and C are:

NTSC: 68 uH + 29,07205272 pF

PAL: 68 uH + 18,95024405 pF

I am looking into "Dual-Standard Luma Trap" implementation of the [AD725](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD725.pdf), page 15, and explanation of its operation.

[image]

My first thought that it must not be so simple as it is being described. Diode must also have its own capacitance at least. And I decided to perform simulation using LTSpice.

No doubt notch filter cancels oscillations at the target frequency effectively:

[image]

Above is an example for PAL and "dual" circuit disconnected. Same is with NTSC if 10.12 pF is connected to ground in parallel to 18.95 pF.

But as soon as I connect the "dual" circuit, as expected, get much worse performance.

[image]

and

[image]

Of course this is real life with some important assumptions (e.g. control signal is not affected by the filter, components are ideal etc).

But anyway the simulation inspired me to look for different solution. The technical task is very simple - just connect capacitor in parallel for second standard.

Well, the modern way (and actually old good one) may be using analog switch. It will add a cost, but the result improvement may also be significant.

I found [TS5A3166](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts5a3166.pdf) / [TS5A3167](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts5a3167.pdf) which must be a good fit in terms of resistance and bandwidth and distortion at 5V supply. Thus the task is just feed control signal to this chip which will connect second capacitor in parallel to the first one.

Did you have similar implementations? Is it a good idea in overall? Anything I overlooked by considering analog switch for this application?

**Update:** I clearly overlooked that TS5A3166 has its own *typical* capacitance, which is comparable to the required capacitance (19pF/35.5pF), and can not be neglected...